# Binding list of images to treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, treeview

I am having few images in a list

```
public List<Image> UniqueDeviceImages
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

I am trying to bind these set of images to a treeview

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
<ItemsControl x:Name="ImagelistControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UniqueDeviceImages}">
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<Image Source="{Binding Path=UniqueDeviceImages,Converter={StaticResource bitmapconvertor }}" Height="15" Width="15" Margin="0,2,4,3"/>
 </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
 </ItemsControl>
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path= UniqueDeviceName}">
  </TextBlock>
 </StackPanel>
```

There is a bitmap convertor which converts Image to Imageresource type. The images are not getting binded to the treeview. The treeview just shows the device name. It does not show any images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataContext of an item container in an ItemsControl is automatically set to the appropriate data item from the `ItemsSource` collection. Hence in your DataTemplate you must not bind again to the `UniqueDeviceImages` property. Just drop the `Path` part of the binding expression:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource bitmapconvertor}}" .../>
```